# Syntax to reference a loop through a specific column range identified from a cell address?

Tags: excel, vba

Cell C1 on my main worksheet is a drop-down list of column headers on an adjacent worksheet called "Options" where C1:J1 are the options. I have this code so far to identify which column on the Options sheet is chosen by the user on the main worksheet.

```
Dim rngX As Range
Set rngX = Worksheets("Options").Range("A1:J1").Find(Range("C1"), lookat:=xlPart)
If Not rngX Is Nothing Then
    'MsgBox Chr(34) & Range("C1").Value & Chr(34) & " found at " & rngX.Address
End If
```

The result is when I make a selection from the dropdown on the "main" worksheet, I know the address of the cell matching that name in the top row of the Options page. I want to execute a particular line of code only depending on if rows 2-81 underneath that header in the options page contain a "Y" or a "N".

If it's Y

```
getNthRegion(ActiveSheet,{{1-80}}).Hidden = False
```

If it's N

```
getNthRegion(ActiveSheet,{{1-80}}).Hidden = True
```

How do I rip the column out of the address I have and use it as input to run something based on the Y/N in the 80 rows beneath that column?

The syntax below is what I'm thinking I need, but I know it doesn't work.

```
    Dim groupcounter As Long 
    For groupcounter = 1 To 80 
        If Worksheets("Options").Range(rngX.Column, groupcounter + 1) = "Y" Then
            getNthRegion(ActiveSheet, groupcounter).Hidden = True 
        ElseIf Worksheets("Options").Range(rng.Column, groupcounter + 1) = "N" Then 
            getNthRegion(ActiveSheet, groupcounter).Hidden = False 
        End If 
     Next groupcounter
```

Comment: Dim groupcounter As Long
    For groupcounter = 1 To 80
        If Worksheets("Options").Range(rngX.Column, groupcounter + 1) = "Y" Then
            getNthRegion(ActiveSheet, groupcounter).Hidden = True
        ElseIf Worksheets("Options").Range(rng.Column, groupcounter + 1) = "N" Then
            getNthRegion(ActiveSheet, groupcounter).Hidden = False
        End If
    Next groupcounter  \\\\ I'm sorry I can't get to format properly. I get an error a the first IF line.

Comment: In the future please edit your post to include snippets of code instead of putting it in the comments. It's much easier to read and will help people help you.

Comment: Thank you, that makes much more sense. I thought I could add it to a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

```
Dim rngX As Range, c As range

Set rngX = Worksheets("Options").Range("A1:J1").Find(Range("C1"), lookat:=xlPart)

If Not rngX Is Nothing Then
    For Each c in rnx.offset(1,0).Resize(80,1).cells
        c.entirerow.Hidden = (c.Value = "N")
    Next c
End If
```

Comment: that hides all of those rows in the Options tab, and not the corresponding groups in the Main tab.

Comment: In that case you'd need to explain a little more exactly what you need to do.  E.g. what exactly would GetNthRegion do?